# Buffer overflow successful, but it shouldn't be?

Tags: gdb, stack, buffer-overflow

This is my program, with a vulnerable char buffer, name[400].

```
void greeting(char *temp1,char *temp2)
{
    char name[400];
    strcpy(name,temp2);
    printf("Hello %s %s\n", temp1, name);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    greeting(argv[1],argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled as follows on Linux (64-bit) with ASLR disabled:

```
gcc -m32 -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -z execstack -o buffer buffer.c

(gdb) run Mr `perl -e 'print "A" x 400'`
Hello Mr AAAAAAA.... (truncated)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()

(gdb) info reg eip ebp
eip            0x41414141
ebp            0x41414141
```

I'm assuming here that a null byte is added, resulting in the overflow, but what I don't understand is how the EIP can be 0x41414141 with only a 1 byte overflow?

EDIT: After more probing with gdb, there is no null byte added, and there is no overflow at all when only 400 bytes are entered. So how does my EIP end up pointing to my buffer contents without any overflow? I'm assuming that the absense of a null byte causes problems for printf().

Comment: "there is no null byte added" ??

Comment: I'm not familiar with perl, and thought it might add a null-byte to my input string, which would cause an overflow (400+1). Checked memory with gdb though and I don't even overflow the buffer, yet my EIP still ends up at 0x41414141.

Comment: C strings are null terminated. you do overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C string are `NUL` terminated, so you end up with a 1-byte overflow with a value of zero (`NUL`).

The one-byte `NUL` overflow modifies the saved value of `$ebp` to point lower on the stack than it should.  This results in restoring an incorrect value into `$esp`, and control of `$eip`.

Take specific note of the value of `ebp`.  After the call, the value of `$ebp` is still the same, but the value it points to (the value which `main` will restore off the stack) has been adjusted, and points into the middle of our controlled buffer.

When `greeting` returns into main, nothing happens.  However, when `main` restores the stack frame with a `leave` instruction, the stack pointer `$esp` is set into the middle of our controlled buffer.  When the `ret` instruction is executed, we have control over `$eip`.

Note that I've used a cyclic pattern generated by [pwntools](http://pwntools.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.3/util/cyclic.html?module-pwnlib.util.cyclic) rather than the standard `AAAAA` since we can use it to calculate offsets.  For example 'aaaa' => 0, 'aaab' => 1, 'aaba' => 2.

### Before Strcpy

```
EBP: 0xffffc6e8 --> 0xffffc6f8 --> 0x0 
ESP: 0xffffc54c --> 0xffffc558 --> 0xffffc5c8 --> 0xf63d4e2e 
EIP: 0x8048466 (<greeting+25>:  call   0x8048320 <strcpy@plt>)
```

### After Strcpy

```
EBP: 0xffffc6e8 --> 0xffffc600 ("raabsaabtaabuaabvaabwaabxaabyaab"...)
ESP: 0xffffc54c --> 0xffffc558 ("aaaabaaacaaadaaaeaaafaaagaaahaaa"...)
EIP: 0x804846b (<greeting+30>:  lea    eax,[ebp-0x190])
```

### Before `leave` in `main`

```
EBP: 0xffffc600 ("raabsaabtaabuaabvaabwaabxaabyaab"...)
ESP: 0xffffc6f0 --> 0xffffc9bb ("Mister")
EIP: 0x80484b1 (<main+39>:      leave)
```

### After `leave` in main

```
EBP: 0x62616172 (b'raab')
ESP: 0xffffc604 ("saabtaabuaabvaabwaabxaabyaabzaac"...)
EIP: 0x80484b2 (<main+40>:      ret)
```

### At `ret` in main

```
EBP: 0x62616172 (b'raab')
ESP: 0xffffc608 ("taabuaabvaabwaabxaabyaabzaacbaac"...)
EIP: 0x62616173 (b'saab')
```